# Does @RestController have a way to do filter or interceptor without Servlet and HttpServletRequest?

Tags: java, spring-boot, security

Is there a way to use spring-boot Restful without "HttpServletRequest" to retrieve client's request and others ?
Like, to intercept a calling to server, has to do a scan, how to do it without Servlet API support?

It is a little strange but really donot know if there is a calling convertion that has already implemented this function. Can it be done by following annoation definitions?

@RequestMapping

1. consumes: It defines an array of consumable media types of mapped
   request.
2. produces: It defines an array of producible media types of mapped request.
3. headers: It defines the acceptable headers of mapped request.
4. params: It defines the parameters of the mapped request, narrowing the primary mapping.
5. path: It defines path mapping URIs in servlet environment.
6. name: It assigns a name to this mapping.
7. value: It defines primary mapping expressed by this annotation.

Thanks :)

Comment: It's not clear from the question what you're trying to achieve, are you trying to get access to `HttpServletRequest` object in your REST method? or are you  trying trying to get access to request details like `HttpHeader, Query Params` ?

Comment: What's the reason you don't want to use a filter?

Comment: Hi @11thdimension, was trying to do filtering and/or interceptor.

Comment: @Francisco Mateo Hi, "Servlet,Controller and RestController, and JMX", and also acutator, seems there are many ways to do securing and filter/interceptor. If it can be done with @param(name="xxx"), why should use filter to handle servlets but not Restful service? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You use Spring boot release between 1.2 - 2.0
You may use Spring Boot Actuator trace endpoint.
You can see last 100 incoming request with trace endpoint.

Add this dependency in your pom file.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Add this configurations in application.properties.

```
endpoints.actuator.enabled=true
endpoints.trace.enabled=true
endpoints.trace.sensitive=false
management.trace.include=request-headers,response-headers,cookies,errors,parameters
```

then make request http://yourhost:yourport/trace  (etc. http://localhost:8080/trace)
see the logs.

If you want to save logs,

you can create your custom trace repository :

```
@Component
public class customTrace implements TraceRepository {

    private final TraceRepository lastOneHundretLogs = new InMemoryTraceRepository();


    @Override
    public List<Trace> findAll() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Map<String, Object> map) {       

    }
}
```

logs is in the lastOneHundretLogs object.you can take it.

As an alternative ,you can log requests with logger

```
@Component
public class InMemoryTraceRepository implements TraceRepository {

    private static final Logger HTTP_LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger("http-logger");

    // For security matters it's better to not expose Traces on HTTP
    @Override
    public List<Trace> findAll() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Map<String, Object> map) {
        Trace trace = new Trace(new Date(), map);
        String traceInfo = trace.getInfo().toString();
        HTTP_LOGGER.info(traceInfo);
    }
}
```

Comment: "Finally, if you need access to web-framework-specific functionality, you can implement Servlet or Spring @ Controller and @ RestController endpoints at the cost of them not being available over JMX or when using a different web framework." From spec of boot. Thanks a lot, @Cocuthemyth. Currently not very sure about this acutator design, and will do a lot of research work.

Comment: it seems spring uses servlet to comprise restful interface, and ready-made acutator has provided a production.